# How to solder wire on Piezo Disc?

Tags: sensor, ultrasound, piezo, piezoelectricity

I am working on a project that has this piezo sensor.

How I can connect wire to it?

[image: Image description]

Comment: What are you having trouble with specifically when soldering wire to it? Your question asks how to connect wire but your title suggests you already know you should solder to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the surface of the piezo has a metallic coating. Without that, you won't be able to solder anything on top of it.
Such coating layers are very thin and tend to detach easily from the ceramic if you apply heat for too long.

Furthermore, the piezo itself is very sensitive to heat and is generally a bad thermal conductor. If you apply too much heat for too long, the piezo's polarization will be destroyed, leading to altered characteristics. The temperature at which polarization breaks is called curie temperature and is typically around 300°C.

I've worked in a project, where we needed to solder some wires to piezo disks from time to time and it was always a pain. Here are some tips:

1.) Keep the contact time of the soldering iron at a minimum. The ceramic will not spread the heat very well and local defects can occure very easily. Also, reducing contact time prevents the detaching of the metallic layer.

2.) Keep the temperature of your soldering iron as low as you can get it with a reasonable contact time. But don't exceed 300°C.

3.) Use a solder with a very low melting temperature. Alternatively, you can try to use conductive glue. It has a higher "contact" resistance and might come off easier if you are vibrating the piezo. But maybe its ok for your application.

4.) Always measure the piezo afterwards. Its the only way to see wheter your soldering was successful. Aim for the impedance vs frequency characteristic.

Comment: your comment was very helpful I need more guidance in the field of piezo . can you help me?

Comment: If this post anwers your specific question, you should mark it as accepted. You can always ask a new question on this forum and I'll try to answer it if I can.